# Python 2.7 OpenCV matchTemplate, Get only the best match

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, opencv

```
THRESHOLD = 0.9
results = cv2.matchTemplate(image, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
locations = numpy.where( results >= THRESHOLD) # <---
```

With the code above (where the arrow is) I can get **all** the matches that are above a certain `threshold`.

But I want just to get the **best match** from the `results` and then check *the best match* if it is above the `threshold` or not. How do I do it?

Note: Please make your answer beginner-friendly.

Comment: you need to use `cv2.minMaxLoc()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You ought to use `cv2.minMaxLoc()`. This will return only one and the best match.

```
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(results)

top_left = max_loc
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)

cv2.rectangle(image.copy(), top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)
```

**Illustration: **

I have Messi on the football ground as the images and his face as the template.

```
img = cv2.imread('C:/Users/selwyn77/Desktop/messi.jpg', 0)
img2 = cv2.imread('C:/Users/selwyn77/Desktop/messi.jpg', 1)
template = cv2.imread('C:/Users/selwyn77/Desktop/messi_face.jpg', 0)
w, h = template.shape[::-1]

#img3 = img2.copy()

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img,template,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

top_left = max_loc
bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)

cv2.rectangle(img2, top_left, bottom_right, (0, 255, 0), 2)

cv2.imshow('img', img2)
```

[image]

**EDIT:**

You can set a threshold and check whether `max_val` is greater than this threshold. If it is greater then proceed to draw the matching region.

```
threshold = 0.85
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(results)
if max_val > threshold:

    top_left = max_loc
    bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
    cv2.rectangle(image.copy(), top_left, bottom_right, 255, 2)
```

Comment: How can I then incorporate the threshold? Since this solution will always a match no matter how terrible the match is. I would like it to not show any match if it is under a certain threshold.